# Change the chapter heading style

Tags: chapters

I need to change the below code found on another page of this site, so as to display the chapter title (e.g. `\chapter{Intro}`) above the horizontal line to the left:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {\filleft%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      outer sep=0pt,
      text width=2.5cm,
      minimum height=3cm,
      fill=myblue,
      font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
      align=center
      ] (num) {\thechapter};
    \node[
      rotate=90,
      anchor=south,
      font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
      ] at ([xshift=-5pt]num.west) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};
    \node[
      font=\color{white}\Large\normalfont,
      anchor=north,
      inner sep=0pt
      ] at ([yshift=2.5cm]num.north) {\chaptertitlename};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*

You could try using the explicit option of `titlesec` and this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% use option explicit
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue} }
{%
\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-4cm}{\LARGE\rmfamily\raggedright#1}\hfill % use a parbox for longer titles   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[
        outer sep=0pt,
        text width=3cm,
        minimum height=3cm,% expanded to accommodate two digits
        fill=myblue,
        font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
        align=center
        ] (num) {\thechapter};
        \node[
        rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
        font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
        ] at ([xshift=-5pt]num.west) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
{4pt}
{\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{9} % test two digits
    \chapter{This is a bigger chapter title that needs to be adjusted here}
\end{document}
```

[image: explicit 2]

Comment: While it seems to work for small chapter titles (thanks for that), what happens when the chapter title is not just a single word but rather a small sentence?? [Not the best outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwwKr.png).

Comment: @gymLyk POLEMI  If such cases are a possibility, a parbox can be used to encapsulate the title. The answer was updated.

Comment: Very good. Thank you @Amélie